# How to connect to SQL Server with Windows authentication from Node.JS

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2019 and the `mssql` module for node js.

when i start the application so it crash on sql connection:

```
var conn = new sql.Connection(dbConfig);
```

Here is my db config:

```
var sql = require("mssql");

var dbConfig = {
    server: "server_name",
    database: "database_name",
    port: 1433,
    driver: "mssql",
    options: {
        trustedConnection: true
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is the problem? If you have an error, please post it

Comment: when i start the application and application create the connection with sql server so application automatically close on that line which mention on above.

Comment: Does it crash with an error message or just exists after making this connection? Any additional details you can provide to understand better your situation?